# Rectangular/square gradient in shader

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

my first question got closed. Since then I've added some code and made some progress. However, the gradient generated is circular and I currently don't know how to transform it into a square.

Here is my current result:

[image]

Target result(along these lines):

[image]

Here is my fragment shader:

```html
precision highp float;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        uniform float centerX;
        uniform float centerY;
        uniform vec4 colors[4];
        uniform float steps[4];

        void main() {
          vec3 map = vec3(vTextureCoord, 1);
          vec2 uv = map.xy;

          float dist = distance(vTextureCoord, vec2(centerX, centerY));
          highp vec4 col = colors[0];
          for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
              col = mix(col, colors[i], smoothstep(steps[i - 1], steps[i], dist));
          }
          float factor = max(abs(uv.x - centerX), abs(uv.y - centerY));
          float c = 1. - max(abs(uv.x - centerX), abs(uv.y - centerY));
          vec4 finalColor = vec4((col.r - factor), (col.g - factor), (col.b - factor), 1.);

          gl_FragColor = finalColor;
        }
```

The parameters passed are:

Colors: [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]

Steps: [0, 0.29, 0.35, 1]

Comment: Rather than use the distance use the max axis distance. eg the following will get max distance from center and normalize it to a value 0-1 `vec2 xyDist = abs(vTextureCoord - vec2(0.5,0.5)); float dist = max(xyDist.x, xyDist.y)/0.5;` you can then interpolate using `dist`.

Comment: Can you give me an example using centerX, centerY? Why divide by 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using texture coordinates

Below is an example that uses texture coordinates in the range 0 - 1 which makes the center of the gradient at `0.5, 0.5`. Thus to compute the gradient we must normalize the distance from the center from the range 0 - 0.5 to 0 - 1. This is done by dividing by 0.5 or the reciprocal (as in example) multiplying by 2 (as multiplication is always the better option than division)

### Simplifying the shader

Also your method of calculating the gradient color at each fragment is computationally expensive. For each gradient (3 in this case) you call `smoothstep` and then `mix`, yet for each fragment 2 of those calculations do nothing of consequence to the computed color.

The example below reduces the computations by checking if the distance is within a particular gradient, and only if within then computes the color assigning to `gl_FragColor` and then breaks out of the loop

I can not workout if you want the gradient to darken to the edges as your first image and code (and accepted answer) suggest, or it is the second image in your question that is the result you want. The example assumes that you want the second image.

```js
const shaders = {
vs: `attribute vec2 vert;
varying vec2 uv;
void main() {
    uv = (vert  + 1.0) / 2.0; // normalize texture coords
    gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0.0, 1.0);
}`, 
fs: `precision mediump float;
varying vec2 uv;  
uniform vec3 colors[4];
uniform float steps[4];
void main(){
    vec2 gradXY = abs(uv - 0.5);  // 0.5 is centerX, centerY
    float dist = pow(max(gradXY.x, gradXY.y) * 2.0, 2.0);
    float start = steps[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        float end = steps[i]; 
        if (dist >= start && dist <= end) {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(colors[i - 1], colors[i], (dist-start) / (end-start)), 1);
            break;
        }
        start = end;
    }
}`,};
const F32A = a => new Float32Array(a), UI16A = a => new Uint16Array(a);
const GLBuffer = (data, type = gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, use = gl.STATIC_DRAW, buf) => (gl.bindBuffer(type, buf = gl.createBuffer()), gl.bufferData(type, data, use), buf);
const GLLocs = (shr, type, ...names) => names.reduce((o,name) => (o[name] = (gl[`get${type}Location`])(shr, name), o), {});
const GLShader = (prg, source, type = gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, shr) => {
    gl.shaderSource(shr = gl.createShader(type), source);
    gl.compileShader(shr);
    gl.attachShader(prg, shr);
}
var W;    
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
requestAnimationFrame(render);
addEventListener("resize", render);
const prog = gl.createProgram();
GLShader(prog, shaders.vs, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
GLShader(prog, shaders.fs);
gl.linkProgram(prog);
gl.useProgram(prog);
const locs = GLLocs(prog, "Uniform", "colors", "steps");
const vert = GLLocs(prog, "Attrib", "vert").vert;
GLBuffer(F32A([-1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1, -1,1]));
GLBuffer(UI16A([1,2,3, 0,1,3]), gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vert);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vert, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 
function render() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, W = canvas.width = Math.min(innerWidth,innerHeight), canvas.height = W);
    gl.uniform3fv(locs.colors, F32A([1,1,1,  1,0,0,  1,1,1,  0,0,0]));
    gl.uniform1fv(locs.steps, F32A([0, 1/3, 2/3, 1]));
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
       margin: 0px;
    }
    canvas {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       background: black;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### Question ambiguities

The are a number of ambiguities in your question which are addressed in the following

The `pow` function in the example line ...

```
float dist = pow(max(gradXY.x, gradXY.y) * 2.0, 2.0);
```

... is the an approximation of your use of `smoothstep(steps[i - 1], steps[i], dist)` when you calculate the col (assuming the dist range of 0 - 0.5). If you want the full Hermite curve you can replace the line with ...

```
float distL = max(gradXY.x, gradXY.y) * 2.0;
float dist = distL * distL * (3.0 - 2.0 * distL);
```

.. and if you want the darkening to the edge as in the questions first image use the following line when calculating the frag color. NOTE assuming colors are `vec4` not `vec3` make appropriate mods if you use the example code.

```c
FragColor = mix(colors[i - 1], colors[i], (dist-start) / (end-start)) - vec4(vec3(distL * 0.5),0);
```

or if not using Hermite curve

```c
FragColor = mix(colors[i - 1], colors[i], (dist-start) / (end-start)) - vec4(vec3(dist * 0.5),0);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it answered many of my questions I had that I did not ask since I had to proceed with other parts of the project. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A square gradient can be achieved by computing the maximum distance of both axis:

<s>`float dist = distance(vTextureCoord, vec2(centerX, centerY));`</s>

```c
vec2 distV = vTextureCoord - vec2(centerX, centerY);
float dist = max(abs(distV.x), abs(distV.y));
```

---

Complete example:

```js
(function loadscene() {    

var canvas, gl, vp_size, prog, bufObj = {};

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "ogl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = gl.createProgram();
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        let source = document.getElementById(i==0 ? "draw-shader-vs" : "draw-shader-fs").text;
        let shaderObj = gl.createShader(i==0 ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
        gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
        let status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
        gl.attachShader(progDraw, shaderObj);
        gl.linkProgram(progDraw);
    }
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(progDraw, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(progDraw));
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation(progDraw, "inPos");
    progDraw.u_time = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_time");
    progDraw.u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_resolution");
    gl.useProgram(progDraw);

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    //vp_size = [256, 256]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function render(deltaMS) {

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_time, deltaMS/1000.0);
    gl.uniform2f(progDraw.u_resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
#version 100

attribute vec2 inPos;
varying vec2 ndcPos;

void main()
{
    ndcPos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 ndcPos;  // normaliced device coordinates in range [-1.0, 1.0]
uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

#define FILL

void main()
{
    vec4 colors[4];
    colors[0] = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    colors[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    colors[2] = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    colors[3] = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    float steps[4];
    steps[0] = 0.2;
    steps[1] = 0.4;
    steps[2] = 0.6;
    steps[3] = 0.8;

    vec2 uv = ndcPos.xy;
    uv.x *= u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;
    
    vec2 vTextureCoord = uv;
    float centerX = 0.0;
    float centerY = 0.0;

    //float dist = distance(vTextureCoord, vec2(centerX, centerY));
    vec2 distV = vTextureCoord - vec2(centerX, centerY);
    float dist = max(abs(distV.x), abs(distV.y));
    
    highp vec4 col = colors[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        col = mix(col, colors[i], smoothstep(steps[i - 1], steps[i], dist));
    }
    float factor = max(abs(uv.x - centerX), abs(uv.y - centerY));
    float c = 1. - max(abs(uv.x - centerX), abs(uv.y - centerY));
    vec4 finalColor = vec4((col.r - factor), (col.g - factor), (col.b - factor), 1.);

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
</script>

<canvas id="ogl-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```